# Is $3-4U$ equivalent to $4(1-U)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

If $U$ is defined to be the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, is it true that 
$3-4U\sim4(1-U)$?

Comment: NB: $3-4U\sim 4(1-U)$ only says they have identical distribution; it does *not* claim that they are equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sim$? Equal everywhere? Equal almost surely? Equal in distribution? Etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

- Are they each uniform on their support?
- What are the highest and lowest possible values of $3-4U$ ?
- What are the highest and lowest possible values of $4(1-U)$ ?
- Do they have the same distribution?